# How to format a map initialization with clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am trying to introduce clang-format in a quite big C++ project. It is going so good except a few cases. The most annoying is the formatting result of a map initialization. I have tried to find regarding flags in clang-format, or any solution by googling it, but I haven't found anything. The problematic code snippet:

```cpp
// before formatting

const std::map<std::type_index, void *> functionMap{
  {typeid(DummyClassAAAAA), (bool (*)(const DummyClassAAAAA &, const DummyClassAAAAA &)) &operator== },
  {typeid(DummyClassBBBB), (bool (*)(const DummyClassBBBB &, const DummyClassBBBB &)) &operator== },
  {typeid(DummyClassCCC), (bool (*)(const DummyClassCCC &, const DummyClassCCC &)) &operator== },
  {typeid(DummyClassDDDDDDDDD), (bool (*)(const DummyClassDDDDDDDDD &, const DummyClassDDDDDDDDD &)) &operator== },
  {typeid(DummyClassEEEEEEE), (bool (*)(const DummyClassEEEEEEE &, const DummyClassEEEEEEE &)) &operator== },
  {typeid(DummyClassFFFFFFFFFF), (bool (*)(const DummyClassFFFFFFFFFF &, const DummyClassFFFFFFFFFF &)) &operator== }
};

// after formatting

const auto functionMap = std::map<std::type_index, void *>{{typeid(DummyClassAAAAA),
  (bool (*)(const DummyClassAAAAA &, const DummyClassAAAAA &)) &operator== },
  {typeid(DummyClassBBBB), (bool (*)(const DummyClassBBBB &, const DummyClassBBBB &)) &operator== },
    {typeid(DummyClassCCC), (bool (*)(const DummyClassCCC &, const DummyClassCCC &)) &operator== },
      {typeid(DummyClassDDDDDDDDD), (bool (*)(const DummyClassDDDDDDDDD &, const DummyClassDDDDDDDDD &)) &operator== },
        {typeid(DummyClassEEEEEEE), (bool (*)(const DummyClassEEEEEEE &, const DummyClassEEEEEEE &)) &operator== },
          {typeid(DummyClassFFFFFFFFFF),
            (bool (*)(const DummyClassFFFFFFFFFF &, const DummyClassFFFFFFFFFF &)) &operator== } };
```

My `.clang-format` file:

```
UseTab: Never
IndentWidth: 2
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
ColumnLimit: 120
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 2
PointerAlignment: Right
DerivePointerAlignment: false
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
AlignTrailingComments: true
IndentCaseLabels: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
```

I am using `clang-format version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)` on Windows.

The only requirement here is that every pair in the initialization list should start on a new line, but in the same column. I wouldn't like to turn off clang-format for any code snippet, so I really would like to solve it by configuring clang-format to produce the right output.

Any idea, how to solve this? Maybe if there is no way to achieve this, then could somebody please provide any proof of that?

### Edit - Solution

After adding additional braces, the result looks like this:

```cpp
const std::map<std::type_index, void *> functionMap{
  {typeid(DummyClassAAAAA), ((bool (*)(const DummyClassAAAAA &, const DummyClassAAAAA &)) & operator==)},
  {typeid(DummyClassBBBB), ((bool (*)(const DummyClassBBBB &, const DummyClassBBBB &)) & operator==)},
  {typeid(DummyClassCCC), ((bool (*)(const DummyClassCCC &, const DummyClassCCC &)) & operator==)},
  {typeid(DummyClassDDDDDDDDD), ((bool (*)(const DummyClassDDDDDDDDD &, const DummyClassDDDDDDDDD &)) & operator==)},
  {typeid(DummyClassEEEEEEE), ((bool (*)(const DummyClassEEEEEEE &, const DummyClassEEEEEEE &)) & operator==)},
  {typeid(DummyClassFFFFFFFFFF), ((bool (*)(const DummyClassFFFFFFFFFF &, const DummyClassFFFFFFFFFF &)) & operator==)},
};
```

Comment: To sure if that is an option for you but adding braces around the values will make the alignment correctly. `{typeid(DummyClassAAAAA), ((bool (*)(const DummyClassAAAAA &, const DummyClassAAAAA &)) &operator==) }`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it helps! For the full solution an extra comma needs to be added after the last item. If you write that also in an answer, I am happy to accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you why `clang-format` does the formating that way in this case, and if it should be considered as a bug.

But in such situations, braces can help to solve the formatting, as it changes the AST and therefore the rules that are applied, and what is used as references for alignment.

Adding braces around the value part will correct the alignment of the map items:

```
{typeid(DummyClassAAAAA),
       ((bool (*)(const DummyClassAAAAA &, const DummyClassAAAAA &)) &
        operator==)}
```

Depending on what overall alignment you want to have in the complete list, you need to add a comma after the last item, to e.g. force the `};` to a new line.